# Extract from the string only IPs and ONLY those that in tags, ignore others

Tags: javascript, string, ip, pattern-matching, match

The source text is something like this, contains IPs between  and just nubmers that looks IP-ish, but actually a garbage, like 999.888.777.669

```
   text_to_parce = "<b>word</b>  <b>192.168.0.1</b> <b>name</b>    999.888.777.669 <b>255.1.1.14<b> <b>address</b>"
```

I need to extract only those that surrounded by tags `<b></b>` to get this:

192.168.0.1
255.1.1.14

I did this:

```
 ip_pattern= /\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b/gi,
userip_array = text_to_parce .match(ip_pattern).join("\n");`
```

But it gives all the numbers, including "fake" IPs and I need ONLY IP (no words) and ONLY those IP that inside the `<b></b>`

I understand that it's might be difficult, but still hope to find help...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of IP address regexes on the web, here is an example [using one I found](http://www.regextester.com/22):

```js
var text_to_parce = "<b>word</b>  <b>192.168.0.1</b> <b>name</b>    999.888.777.669 <b>255.1.1.14<b> <b>address</b>";

var validIP = /(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])/g;

console.log(text_to_parce.match(validIP))
```

If you need to ensure it is wrapped in a `<b>` tag, you can just add that to both sides of the regex

Comment: Yes... but how to do it... I tried everything, but i cant figure out the regex...

Comment: Thank you! But something wrong a bit, you see- the last IP is 255.1.1.1 it should be 255.1.1.14 --- for some reason it takes only 1st digit everywhere...